# JavaScript/AngularJS: Force refresh on site for js and css files

Tags: javascript, caching, versioning

I have had the same issue for a while now that when publishing a new version of the site the user will have to do a hard refresh to remove any previous cached files. 
I know this question has been asked before, but the responses I have found are fairly old and I'm wondering if there is a better solution.

The best method, as far as I'm aware, is to add a version number onto the end of all your files.  -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js?1500"></script>
```

And for every release of the website you update to ?1501 etc.

However this means I have to manually update the number for all the files I am using (since I am not using any mvc stuff that could take care of this automatically). This is of course doable but not ideal. Is there a simpler way of handling this for a pure angular/JavaScript based website that i'm not aware of or have been unable to find?

Answer (score 0):

There are building tools that you need to use, eg. for Grunt: https://github.com/cbas/grunt-rev
It will automatically take care about versioning of your js files.